# Is it possible to display a tray icon with appindicator and a bash script?

Tags: indicator, system-tray

If I understand correctly, the [Gnome shell extension appindicator](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator), is used to display tray icons in the activities bar, on the top right of the screen.

Is it possible to display a tray icon with a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch a program in it that lets you make a systray icon, such as [Yet Another Dialog (yad)](https://github.com/v1cont/yad).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not what I was looking for, but there might be no other solution.